# SSRS : Need to run SSRS reports on sharepoint site using SSIS

Tags: reporting-services, ssis

I have created few SSRS reports in SQL server 2012 with Visual Studio 2010 version.

And I have deployed them to one SharePoint Site.

I want to make this automated, so that data available in the reports are up to date.

So, now I would like to create SSIS package which will run periodically to get up to date data using integration services. I am very much new to SSIS. I have tried to look at different sites for this, but I am not getting an exact idea from where to start.

Can anyone please guide me on this? How can I create a WSDL file URL for the SharePoint report? Do I really need it if report is already made in SSRS or do I just want to run that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Would [SSRS caching](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927.aspx) solve your problem?

Otherwise, there's nothing SSIS specific to solving your problem. You will simply need to use the .NET library to visit the page with the appropriate parameters. Visit your report page and copy the full URL.

Inside a `Script Task` use that URL as part of the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28VS.80%29.aspx). You'll probably need to supply credentials with this. No need to deal with storing the output, you'll simply want to validate that you get a 200 message code

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to automate the running of the Reporting Services reports? In that case you should look at [Report Subscriptions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159762.aspx).

Comment: Nathan, the question is how to refresh Tabular Database using SSIS? or is there any other easy way to do this?

Comment: After whole day work done, I was able to figure out to create package and schedule a job to refresh the package which will refresh the tabular database. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jtarquino/archive/2012/10/24/how-to-refresh-a-tabular-model.aspx ... this is the link I followed. But now, I don't have Analysis service installed on SQL Server 2012 currently. I understand that I need to setup it in Tabular Mode and then Create a Job in SQL Agent and then I will schedule it. Please correct me if I am wrong. I will do this Setup tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mitta, your original question is about reports and does not mention Analysis Services tabular models at all, these are not related to Reporting Services. Perhaps you can update your question to better describe what you are actually trying to do?